# Do databases implement algorithms like binary search etc?

Tags: database, data-structures

All the big companies focus a lot on data structures to improve performance. Do databases implement standard searching and organizing data in memory algorithms like binary search, BST, merge sort etc?

Since different algorithms are good for different data sets, if databases implement them then how can one find out which database implements which algorithms?

Comment: see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work), if you wanna know what algorithm has been implemented, I think that you have to search for it, there is no such thing as `getDatabaseSearchAlgorithm(DB);`

Comment: Why do we have different types of databases then? Like InnoDB and others

Comment: And by method i was referring to maybe some article, document or blog out there which I couldn't find containing this information.

Comment: InnoDB is a database Engine and not a database,  and you should distinguish the difference between (database storage structure)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_storage_structures], and the database search algorithms.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry I haven't gotten back to you yet, haven't had enough time to even read the link. I'll make sure to do it ASAP.